# How can I easily determine the z-ordering of objects in multiple glDraw calls?

Tags: opengl

I have a simple 2D tile-based scene that I'm rendering with OpenGL. On each frame I first draw the static background, and then draw the dynamic elements (monsters, etc.). This way it seems that the later drawn elements "paint over" the earlier drawn ones (using separate `glDraw` calls).

However, when asking around, it seems that if I used a depth buffer the order in which things are drawn doesn't necessarily matter, as the depth buffer can be used to determine visibility.

But what happens when some things share the same z-value when using a depth buffer? Is the newer one "painted over" the older one?

If so, should I rely on this behavior, or rather use different z-values for my "layers"?

Comment: What happens on same depth depends on the depth operation you have setup. Default is to discard the fragment. Depth testing is off by default so later is always on top. Oh, and dont trust the defaults. Vendors are jerks.

Comment: Oh and order does matter for translucent stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When 2 objects share the same z coordjnate and are painted over one another, you get an effect called z fighting (I once heard it being called z achne), parts of each model gets visible, but they generate a strange texture.

This eventually happens less closer to the eye, because the depth buffer keeps a longer range of bits for them than the parts far back.

You can make this effect disappear, by giving each entity a slight offset according to their y coordinate in the vertex shader.

Comment: Since the coordinates are in floats, would it make sense to offset just by something like `1e-6`?

Comment: It depends on what your near plabe is set to. If you have a plane at 10 cm (0.1f), you will see 300m error at 1 km. I think a 0.01 between entites will work, but you need to experiment woth that.

Comment: @Jakub Arnold You need to assume, the user has the worst possible options for everything, or you need to create a fallback. For example, the smallest depthBuffer has 16 bits to work with, that's 2^16 places to put a plane (65536). Around 2/3 of it is positioned between the player and half of the frustum. But let's assume it's linear, so it is easier to calcilate with it. 1/65536 is 0.0000152, so, if you want to be safe, then leave a 0.0001 gap between every entity.